# Twisted: how to wrap a function that takes a call back?

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to use twisted framework for some async programming task recently. One thing I do not quite understand is how to wrap a function which takes a call back function and make it an function that return a deferred object?

For example if I have a function like below:

```
def registerCallbackForData(callback):
   pass # this is a function that I do not control, some library code
```

And now the way I use it is to just register a callback. But I want to be able to  incorporate this into the twisted framework, returning a deferred object probably and use reactor.run() later. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert_callback_to_deferred(f):
    def g():
        d = Deferred()
        d.addCallback(callback)
        f(d.callback)
        return d
    return g

from somelib import registerCallbackForData

getSomeDeferredForData = convert_callback_to_deferred(registerCallbackForData)

d = getSomeDeferredForData()
d.addCallback(...)
...
```

However, bear in mind that a `Deferred` can produce at most one result.  If `registerCallbackForData(cb)` will result in `cb` being called more than once, there is nowhere for the 2nd and following calls' data to go.  Only if you have an at-most-once event source does it make sense to convert it to the `Deferred` interface.

Answer (score -1):

[defer.maybeDeferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.maybeDeferred.html) will wrap a blocking function call to return a deferred. If you want the call to be non-blocking you can instead use [threads.deferToThread](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#deferToThread).

You can see the difference by switching which call is commented out:

```
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, threads


def foo():
    print "going to sleep"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "woke up"
    return "a result"


def show_result_and_stop_reactor(result):
    print "got result: %s, stopping the reactor" % result
    reactor.stop()


print "making the deferred"
d = defer.maybeDeferred(foo)
# d = threads.deferToThread(foo)

print "adding the callback"
d.addCallback(show_result_and_stop_reactor)

print "running the reactor"
reactor.run()
```

Comment: These two APIs help you create a Deferred with a result from a function call.  The OP asked about creating a Deferred from a callback made by another library, though.  These two APIs don't really help in that case.